# Sufficient conditions for a C* algebra to be separable

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Do you know of any (necessary and) sufficient conditions for a C* algebra to be separable?
Reference to bibliography is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a condition that is interesting. But it is easy to show that $A$ is separable if and only if it is generated by a finite or a countable  set.

So as long as you have finite or countably many generators, your algebra will be separable. The vast majority of the commonly used C$^*$-algebras are like that. Exceptions would be the infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebras (and AW$^*$-algebras, but these are not as sexy).

The proof is extremely simple: if $A$ is separable, take $X\subset A$ countable and dense; then $A=C^*(X)$. Conversely, if $X$ is finite or countable and $A=C^*(X)$, then $$Y=\left\{\sum_{j=1}^m (a_j+ib_j)x_{1,j}\cdots x_{n,j}:\ n,m\in\mathbb N,\ a_j,b_j\in\mathbb Q,\ x_{k,j}\in X\cup X^*\right\}$$ is countable and dense.

Comment: Your answer interests me a lot:how can it be shown that an algebra is separable iff it is generated by  a finite or a countable set of elements? Please, just provide a reference if available. I am interested in infinite von Neumann algebras, especially the type III algebras found in Algebraic Quantum Field Theory, which by the aforementioned argument are non-separable. Aren't they?

Comment: It's a two-liner, so I don't think there's a reference; I have included the argument. And yes, any type III von Neumann algebra is not separable as a C$^*$-algebra. They are usually separable as von Neumann algebras, though, when one uses the sot or wot topologies.

Comment: @MartinArgerami But this doesn't really say so much, since we can have many sets of generators right? For example, I think it is easy to prove with the same arguments that a $C^*$-algebra generated by a separable set is again separable; do you agree with this example or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what is "this", that doesn't say so much.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Hi, I am refering to the condition about having at most countable many generators. My point is, *if* what I am saying about algebras generated by separable sets being separable, that an algebra might be generated by an uncountable set and again be separable (and yes, of course it will also be generated by a countable set, but this might not be apparent at first sight).

Comment: @MartinArgerami If what I am saying is creating confusion then don't mind me, I'm just sort of thinking out loud!

Comment: It doesn't really gain you anything to think like that. Any vector space/algebra over the real/complex is uncountable, so of course you can take the whole space/algebra as the set of (uncountably many) generators. You can do this on $\mathbb R$ itself. As a real vector space it is one-dimensional, so it is generated by a single generator; but nothing prevents you to consider the (very useless) uncountable set of generators $\mathbb R$. The point of generators is to have some kind of minimal set that generates the whole thing.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I agree. I came here because I am dealing with a $*$-homomorphism that takes values in a $C^*$-algebra generated by a separable subset and I want to infer that the target $C^*$-algebra is separable. I am just mentioning this because at first I thought "hey, this is not a countable set of generators" but then I said "yeah, but maybe some other set of generators is countable and I can still hope for separability". Thanks for the feedback!